# Getting NaN when trying to add numbers using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to add unknown number of arguments without a loop. here's what I have done so far.

```
var add = function add() {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);

    console.log(args[0], arguments);
    args.splice(0, 1);
    return args[0] + add.apply(this, args); //needtoreadaboutapply
  }
};
```

and this is the output I get when I call add(3,4,5). 
So **what am I doing wrong and how can I debug such recursive calls in browser console?**
`3 [3, 4, 5]
4 [4, 5]
5 [5]
NaN`

Answer (score 3):

You are removing one element from the argument and accessing the same. So that action will cause problem when dealing with last parameter. When you remove the last parameter the array will be `[]` empty, at that time if you access `arg[0]` that will give you `undefined`. `undefined + number = NaN`.

Try to use the removed number instead of accessing it from the array,

```
var add = function add() {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var spliced = args.splice(0, 1);
    console.log(args[0], arguments);
    return spliced[0] + add.apply(this, args); //needtoreadaboutapply
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't stuck with using recursive functions, you might want to look into using .reduce()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
var add = function add() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return args.reduce(function(sum, num) {
    return sum + num;
  }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `return args[0]+add.apply(this,args);` to `return arguments[0]+ add.apply(this,args)`

In the question, I made a mistake of splicing args first and then referencing args[0].

Comment: But that's how I solved my issue so this is actually an answer

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't see that this an answer. If it is an answer, explain it in a better way so that others could understand it.